# How to populate data from class model to tableview

Tags: swift, tableview, swifty-json

My data is coming in modal class named Menu by creating its object menus. Now How can i send the menu names to tableview to show in particular cell

```
 var menus = [Menu]()
                    for (_, content) in json {
                        let menu = Menu(id: Int(content["id"].stringValue),
                            name: content["name"].string,
                             image: content["image"].string,
                            coupon: content["coupon"].int,
                            icon: content["icon"].string,
                            order: Int(content["order"].stringValue),
                            aname: content["name"].string,
                            options: Int(content["options"].stringValue),
                            subcategory:content["subcategory"].arrayObject)

                        menus.append(menu)
                    }
                    for menu in menus {
                        print(menu.name)
                        print(menu.id)
                        print(menu.subcategory)
                    }
                    print(menus.count)
```

Here All the data is saved in Menu class by the help of menus object.I have added the codes to show data to tableview. here i have created custom tableview and trying to populate it

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return menus.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Menucell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! MENUTableViewCell

    cell.Ordermenu.text = ("  \(menus[indexPath.row])")///here its not fetching the value
    return cell


    }
```

Its not working . how the implementation should be ?

[image]

It shows the projectName.classname

updated after accepting answer
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below line of code. Hope it will help you...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Menucell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! MENUTableViewCell
let menu : Menu =  menus[indexPath.row]
cell.Ordermenu!.text = menu. name
return cell


}
```

Comment: yeah but the value is coming in optional value like this  optional(value)

Comment: Can you give screenshot of screen after change in code as per my answer?

Comment: but before each particular value the optional is written

Comment: `cell.Ordermenu.text =menu. name!`try this

Comment: yeah Thanks @Payal

Answer (score 0):

Do you register the table cells? Try something like this...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    var cell: MENUTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MENUTableViewCellIDENTIFIER") as? MENUTableViewCell

    if cell == nil
    {
        let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName:"MENUTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier:"MENUTableViewCellIDENTIFIER")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MENUTableViewCellIDENTIFIER") as! CompactIncidentCellView
        //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    }

    // work with cell here...
    cell.Ordermenu.text = ("  \(menus[indexPath.row])")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: actually i has tried to display a single message and made the number of rows counting fixed its working.

Comment: the problem is in " menus.count" its not retrieving the counting from menu class model

Comment: Ohh. i got the answer actually .I forget to reload the tableview

Comment: the counting i got but in place of (menus[indexPath.row]) what should be there?

Comment: because it shows the "projectName.classname" in tableview